# Why can we not use dynamic arrays as parameters of functions that use static array parameters?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I'm studying the C language and data structures. I wish to get some detailed explanation about why we cannot use dynamic arrays as parameters of functions that use static array parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumAry2D_f1(int ary[][3], int rows, int cols);
void freeAry2D(int **ary, int rows);

int main(void)
{
    int ary2D[][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }; // static array

    int r, c;
    int **ary = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2); // dynamic array
    for (r = 0; r < 2; r++)
    ary[r] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

    for (r = 0; r < 2; r++)
        for (c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            ary[r][c] = r + c; // 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3

    printf("sumAry2D_f1() %d\n", sumAry2D_f1(ary2D, 2, 3));

    // why we can`t function like this?
    // printf("sumAry2D_f1~3() %d\n", sumAry2D_f1(ary, 2, 3));

    freeAry2D(ary, 2); // free function of dynamic array

    return 0;
}

int sumAry2D_f1(int ary[][3], int rows, int cols)
{
    int i, j, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            sum += ary[i][j];

    return sum;
}

void freeAry2D(int **ary, int rows)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    free(ary[i]);
    free(ary);
}
```

Comment: `int ary[][3]` doesn't match to `int **`. E.g `int ary[][3]` (aka `int (*ary)[3]`) point to `[int[3]][int[3]]...`.  `int **ary` point to `[int *][int *]...`.

Comment: Please don't add junk text to get past the "mostly code" filter.

Comment: I`m sorry if you felt bad. Today, I encounter Stack Overflow at first and the phrase made me embarrassed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Answer (score 0):

```
 // why we can`t function like this?
 // printf("sumAry2D_f1~3() %d\n", sumAry2D_f1(ary, 2, 3));
```

Your function specifically expects a pointer to an integer pointer that points to a sequence of 3 integers, or an array of 3-element integer arrays, not just any pointer to integer pointer. `ary` is just a pointer to integer pointer. Although you made your `int **` have the same structure as your `int [][3]`, it could have been different and the compiler can't tell because the memory allocation occurs at run-time, hence if you uncomment the code it probably won't compile, and even if it does the behavior will be undefined.

Unfortunately, you would need 2 functions to do what you want:

```
int sumAry2D_f1(int ary[][3], int rows, int cols);
```

and

```
int sumAry2D_f12(int** ary, int rows, int cols);
```

The code inside each function would be the same.

Comment: Thx. Your explanation was very helpful in understanding what I curious about!!

Comment: Nope. Don't forget to like the answers you find useful, it encourages people to help.